# EPS file looks great in AI but washed out in Mac Preview or ghostscript

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png, color-spaces, eps, imagemagick

I have an EPS file that, when opened in Illustrator, looks great. AI can export to a PNG that also looks great.

When I open this file with Preview on OSX, or use ghostscript/imagemagick to convert it to a PNG, it looks washed out.

AI version:

[image: AI version]

Preview version:

[image: OSX Preview version]

Many of the darker greens are black layers with transparency laid over a green layer. It looks like some sort of color space conversion problem but AFAICT I'm not asking for a color space conversion.

What's going on? How can I use imagemagick/ghostscript to generate a normal-looking PNG of this EPS?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely looks like a cmyk to rgb conversion issue.

Your eps file is probably set as a CMYK document. You can create a new RGB document and copy/paste from the original file, but you lose the CMYK data.

If you plan to use this artwork in both color spaces you'll have to maintain two versions.